# I am trying to write a a transpiler with python's ply but i can only read and convert one line of a code

Tags: python, yacc, lex, transpiler, ply

```
lexer = lex.lex()

precedence = (
    ('left', 'ADD', 'SUB'),
    ('left', 'MULTI', 'DIV'),
    ('left', 'RPAREN', 'LPAREN')
)


def p_expression_term(p):
    '''
    expression : term ENDOFLINE
               | var_assign ENDOFLINE
               | empty
    '''

    p[0] = p[1]


def p_expression_empty(p):
    'empty : '
    pass


def p_expression_add(p):
    'term : term ADD term'

   


def p_expression_sub(p):
    'term : term SUB term'
    


def p_term_multi(p):
    '''term : term MULTI term '''
    


def p_term_div(p):
    '''term : term DIV term'''
   


def p_term_pow(p):
    'term : term POW term'
    p[0] = pow(p[1], p[3])


def p_term_factor(p):
    'term : factor'
    p[0] = p[1]


def p_factor_num(p):
    'factor : NUMBER'
    p[0] = ['number' p[1]]


def p_expressionParenth(p):
    '''term : LPAREN term RPAREN'''
    p[0] = p[2]
    pass


def p_var_assign1(p):
    '''var_assign : NAME EQUAL NAME
                  | NAME EQUAL term
    '''

    p[0] = ast_tree.ast_name1(p[1], p[3])


def p_var_assignBe(p):
    '''var_assign : LET NAME BE term'''

  


def p_var_assign3(p):
    '''var_assign : NAME IDENTIFIER EQUAL term'''

 


# Error rule for syntax errors
def p_error(p):
    print("Syntax error in input! at " + str(p))



# Build the parser
parser = yacc.yacc()

while True:
    try:
        s = '''let x be 12;'''

    except EOFError:
        break
    if not s: continue

    result = parser.parse(s)
    result = ast_tree.fill_locations(result)
    print(ast.unparse(result))
    exit()
```

I am trying to write a transpiler with python's ply but i can only read and convert one line of a code.
this is my yacc class code. i am currently parsing the code in the expression_term method.
I have tried some other solutions that i found on github but it didn't work.
how i can run and parse multiple lines in one input can you give me a code snippet to do that ?
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your grammar only accepts one expression, so the parser is doing exactly what you told it to do. If you want it to parse multiple expressions, you need a grammar which defines the syntax of the list. That might look something like this:

```
program : empty
        | program expression
```

You will have to remove the empty production from `expression`, because multiple consecutive empty objects are ambiguous (how many empty strings are there in an empty sequence?). And you need to make sure `program` is the start symbol.

Comment: thanks  a lot, I am trying to do that but it only gives infinite recursion error.

Comment: @beton: that probably means you missed the base case (`program : empty`).